# Create Image of an area in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, image

I want to create a big image of [this area](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=14/-26.8067/-55.0194). But with a bigger zoom level. How can I achieve this?

Currently I would zoom in, make a screenshot and put those screenshots together with a image editor. But this can't be the fastest solution for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap is the most used approach for your task.

Another tool is taho.exe (if you are on Windows). You can learn more about it from here:

http://www.dimitri-junker.de/eng/html/openstreetmap.html

You can switch the language to English under `Bearbeiten -> Optionen`. An English help manual is included in the Docu folder.

You can also use the Openlayers plugin inside QGIS to create screenshots. These are saved already georeferenced, so stitching them together is a bit easier than with an image editor.

The print composer of QGIS lets you add a legend, and manually added items as well.

Comment: More general, you are looking for static map APIs/tools: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Static_map_images

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this link could help you
[OSM on Paper](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper)
In this page you can find several ways to print your map. You can try these services and choose the one those you prefer.
Maybe the best and quick way to print a map is this [OSMatic](http://maposmatic.org/): you can choose the area to print and the layout. In the printed map, there is the Streets index.

Comment: can you explain (expand this answer) it is currently a weak answer.

Comment: As first sorry, but the linked page is an "institutional page" of OSM and is difficult that could be changed or removed. It's difficult to summarize all the methods described there, and I  can't describe one of those since I don't know what juergen_d exactly needs. In any case, I added more details to my reply. I hope could be better.